# How to disable RECS* warnings in with Roslyn compiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, warnings, compiler-warnings, roslyn

After updating to C# 6 and VS2015 in some projects I have started to see a lot of build warnings like these:

> RECS0119 'string.Compare' is culture-aware
>   RECS0017 Possible compare of value type with 'null'
>   RECS0063    'StartsWith' is culture-aware and missing a StringComparison argument
>   RECS0060 'IndexOf' is culture-aware and missing a StringComparison argument
>   RECS0027 Operator 'is' can be used
>   RECS0133 Parameter name differs in base declaration

Here is the screenshot of one of the suggestions:

[image: String.Compare is culture-aware]

These are valid suggestions for code improvements, but these are all coming from a class that is installed by a nuget package (PetaPoco, I'm looking at you!) and I don't want to modify that file in any way. And I don't want to see these warnings.

I have tried using `#pragma warning disable RECS0060` and variations, but could not make the warnings disappear. Is there a way to disable these Roslyn code improvements warnings on per-file basis? Don't want to hide them for all classes as these come useful sometimes.

Comment: BTW, those warnings seem to come from [Refactoring Essentials](https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/blob/master/RefactoringEssentials/CSharp/Diagnostics/CSharpDiagnosticIDs.cs), not Roslyn itself.

Comment: You could create a separate project, install the NuGet package there and then disable the RE diagnostics in that project. It's a little messy but I think you can't disable-enable warnings -- it's all or nothing.

Comment: @svick That is indeed Refactoring Essentials. I did not even realise I have installed. Care to write up an answer to get points?

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017 you can right click the error number in the errors window and find an entry that should read something like "suppress" (sorry, working in german). There you can choose to suppress the message with a pragma in code or project wide via a file named "GlobalSuppressions.cs". Both works fine.